# Windows Update not working on 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus, windows-update

We have a 2012 Server which is failing to install updates, just searching online, WSUS forever to get updates. I tried rebooting and running the WSUS stop, renaming the Softwaredistribution folder and tried to install some patches manually, but the installation is taking forever too.

Even the manual installation is also taking forever. I checked windowsupdate log file and the logs says no approved patches, but when i checked online and for WSUS updates, for the effectiveness, it is taking forever to search for updates.

Please help me in getting this resolved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the commands:

> ```
> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
> ```

Then reinstalling any Service Pack files? (yes, 2012 doesn't have SP files yet)http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821

Comment: yes, I have done the above as well, yet issue persists. Scanhealth says no errors and even tried the Restorehealth as well, but still the same. :(